# Constructor isn't running but instance is created

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to create an instance of a class, but for some reason the constructor isn't running.

First I define the class here, and pass it to a new instance of `Server` like this (works):

```
class MyMatchMaker extends MatchMaker {
  public autoStartClientCount: 2
}

new Server({
  matchMaker: MyMatchMaker
})
```

Next I take the options passed in and merge the defaults with the user defined options (works). Then I call `new this.settings.matchMaker(this)` It runs, and creates a new instance of `MyMatchMaker`.

```
export interface MatchMakerType<T extends MatchMaker> {
  new(server: Server): MatchMaker
}

export interface Options {
  matchMaker: MatchMakerType<MatchMaker>
}

export class Server {
  private readonly matchMaker!: MatchMaker
  public readonly settings: Options
  public readonly ps: Partial<Options> = {
    matchMaker: undefined
  }

  public constructor(options: Options) {
    this.settings = Object.assign(this.ps, options) as Options
    this.matchMaker = new this.settings.matchMaker(this)
    console.log(this.matchMaker)
  }
}
```

A new instance is created, however, the constructor of this class doesn't run, also a new instance of `WaitList` is not created either.

```
export abstract class MatchMaker {

  public waitList: WaitList = new WaitList

  public constructor(server: Server) {
    console.log('match maker')
  }
}
```

What is causing this to happen?

---

When I dump `this.matchMaker` I get this in the node console (this includes settings I trimmed out from above):

```
MyMatchMaker {
  server:
   Server {
     clients: [],
     ps:
      { port: 5555,
        workers: -1,
        game: 'C:\\Users\\rnaddy\\Documents\\vscode\\projects\\red5-test\\build\\TickTacToe.js',
        type: 'websocket',
        redis: undefined,
        matchMaker: [Function: MyMatchMaker] },
     settings:
      { port: 5555,
        workers: -1,
        game: 'C:\\Users\\rnaddy\\Documents\\vscode\\projects\\red5-test\\build\\TickTacToe.js',
        type: 'websocket',
        redis: undefined,
        matchMaker: [Function: MyMatchMaker] },
     matchMaker: [Circular] },
  game: 'C:\\Users\\rnaddy\\Documents\\vscode\\projects\\red5-test\\build\\TickTacToe.js',
  autoStartClientCount: 2 }
```

Comment: Why do you have `new WaitList` rather than `new WaitList()`?

Comment: I prefer the look of that since `()` are optional

Comment: Your constructor takes in options, maybe because you aren't providing any means it will use the default constructor?

Comment: hmm... When I take the posted code, and create its own contained node app, it works. It just doesn't work with my project for some reason...

Comment: I have figured it out, I moved the `MatchMaker.ts` file, and it was using the old version, since ts doesn't delete files when they are moved to a new location so `MatchMaker.ts -> MatchMaker/MatchMaker.ts` it must have been reading the old file instead of the directory's `index` file

Comment: `Object.assign(this.ps, options) as Options` is modifying the `ps` variable, which is probably not what you want. You instead need `Object.assign({}, this.ps, options) as Options` to not change it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: That is what I want. All I care about is the result of `assign`, I don't care about `this.ps` at any point after